Elementary proof that every state in an irreducible, finite-state Markov chain must be positive-recurrent
Is there an elementary proof of the fact that every state in an irreducible, finite-state Markov chain must be positive-recurrent? I know every state must be recurrent, but I am unable to rule out the null-recurrence case. Every proof that I came across online uses facts like Wald's inequality.

Since the chain is finite and irreducible, there is a number $N\in\{1,2,\dots\}$ and $p>0$ such that
$$
(*)\qquad \mathbb{P}(X_n=j \text{ for some }n=1,2,\dots,N\mid X_0=i)\ge p
\quad \text{for all }i,j.
$$
Fix some state $j$.
For $k=0,1,2,\dots$ let
$$
A_k=\{\text{the walk does not visit state $j$ during the steps }n=Nk+1,Nk+1,Nk+2,\dots,Nk+N\}
$$
From $(*)$ we get that $\mathbb{P}(A_{k}\mid X_0,X_1,\dots,X_{Nk})\le 1-p<1$
Let
$$
\tau=\min\{k\ge 1:\ A_k^c\text{ occured}\},
$$
then $\mathbb{P}(\tau\ge m)\le (1-p)^m$ so $\tau$ is bounded by a geometric random variable with mean $1/p$. Therefore the expected time to hit $j$ is bounded by $N\mathbb{E}\tau\le N/p<\infty$.

Thank you for this. In (∗), why is it "for some $i=1,2,\dots, N$"? Should it be "for some $n = 1,2,\dots, N$"?

Yes, thank you, typo corrected.
